# Is there a way to find a history of the questions I've viewed on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

My question is about a possible feature this site might have.

The problem is that I've lost track of what I was doing on Stack Exchange this morning because I've been dealing with students, work, and family while also going through questions here. It's the second time this kind of thing has happened. I guess it's a bad work situation right now because of the holidays. Noisy.

Anyway, because of all the multi-tasking, I misplaced a piece of information here that's a little important to me. It's not the end of the world, but I really wish I could find it.

It would be really handy if Stack Exchange maintains a history of which questions I've looked since I last logged in and if that history is easily accessible to me.

Does anyone know if it does maintain a list like that which I can access the next time something like this happens? Or maybe even this time?

By the way, I can't merely back up my browser, because my multitasking involved my browser. It's complicated, but the important thing, I'm hoping, is that I didn't log out of Stack Exchange.

I've just been doing too many things this morning and haven't been able to keep it all straight. So I'm wondering if Stack Exchange knows which questions I've looked at since logging in?

Does anyone know?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason why your browser history isn't able to do this? It keeps a log of the webpages you've visited.

Comment: Good question and you're right. There's no good reason, but I had been bouncing around to several sites and I was hoping for a shortcut.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Exchange does not keep a browsable history of the pages you've visited. ([Here's a declined feature request for exactly that.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30500/152515))

[The Activity page of your profile](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) does store some other histories which might help:

- [Your *all actions* tab](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=all) will list posts, comments, edits, and other actions you've taken recently.
- [Your *votes* tab](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes) will list all votes you've cast on questions and answers recently. Maybe you upvoted or downvoted something on the same page as that information. If you have the privilege for casting close, reopen, or delete votes, they'll be here too.
- [Your *responses* tab](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses) will list all comments on this site you've gotten recently that pinged you. This is also visible in your inbox up in the top right. Did anyone ping you on that page?
- In the upper right of your Activity section is [your flag history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current). This is all flags you have cast on questions, answers, and comments. If you have cast a flag in the vicinity of that post, you'll see it here.

Otherwise you'll just have to open your browser history and type `rpg` or `stackexchange` or `rpg.stackexchange.com` into your history search to filter it down to this site.

(Most information on the Activity page of your profile is publicly visible, some is private. Your votes tab is completely private to only you; not even diamond moderators can see it. Your flags and responses are also private but diamond moderators can see them.)

Comment: I didn't know I could identify a subsection of my browser history. I think this answers my question. The problem was that I couldn't "back up" using my browser and reasonably expect to find what I wanted - simply because I'd been moving around too much. Thank you for the great answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, Firefox and Chrome both have a search bar in your history for filtering it. :) You can use that to filter by page title or URL.